# Add CSS hover state from jQuery so that defined CSS can work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

***Question title may seems you already asked question but result has not been given or not work as expected***

My question is: I have some CSS defined on style sheet like:

```
.mydiv:hover {background-color:red}
```

So it will simply add background color whenever user hover on mydiv class

I want to do same things from jquery or javascript whenever a button click happen. I have tried like:

```
<script>
   $("button").click(function(){
       $(".mydiv").trigger("mouseover")
   })
<script>
```

FYI mouseover, mouseenter, mousedown, hover() has already been applied. Please guys have a look on it, its really tricky. For limitation, I could not use any other class with mydiv and toggleClass() function to make same effect. Just need hover effect trigger from JS.

Comment: *"I could not use any other class with mydiv and toggleClass() function to make same effect. Just need hover effect trigger from JS."* why? why can't you use a class? It is not possible to trigger the hover state from JS, all that `.trigger(event)` does is call the registered event handler. It does not really trigger that event in the browser.

Comment: Did you try adding this inside button click: $("#mydiv").addClass("hover"). Please check and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :focus pseudoclass in the css. I think it will work for you

Or

You can just add class on the mydiv tag onclick of button and put you css in that class

Comment: could not got you properly and one more thing is hover css coming from external source. Above i have just mimic same thing

Answer (score 0):

I have Sample Answer :

```js
   $("#btn").on('click',function(){
    $(".mydiv").addClass("testclass");
   });
```

```css
 .testclass{
    background-color: red;
 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "mydiv">
Text is here
</div>

<button id ="btn">
click
</button>
```

Are you Expenceted like this?

Comment: I know how add class or css from script

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Bro:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $('.mydiv').on("myHover", function(){
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
 });    
 $('.mydiv').trigger("myHover");
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro, but i can not add css from script. CSS animation coming from elementor and it works on element hover only. I want , if hover a .card div trigger .mydiv hover as if normal hover so that css animation not only work for .mydiv hover but also work if .card got hover

Comment: if you are using Elementor, then i think i know the reason. To make jQuery functions work with Elementor - the best way is change all $ symbol into jQuery and you be fine. Please try again with something like this:   **jQuery("button").click(function(){
       jQuery(".mydiv").hover();
   })**

Comment: But it should normally,  i tried without elementor and its not work. U can check it

Comment: Sorry for my copy-paste mistake, in your case if i right (about the Elementor jQuery) just this is ok **jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("button").click(function(){
     jQuery('.mydiv').css('color', 'red');
})
});**